# how to get facebook user work and education info and store in to variables or array php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array, associative-array

i am facing problem in storing work and education information of Facebook user.

this is how i am getting info of user:

```
$profile_request=$fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,work,education');
```

and then convert the response in to multidimensional array:

```
$profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
```

this is how i get the response:

```
$profile=Array
    (
    "name" => "abc pqr",
    "first_name" => "abc",
    "last_name" => "pqr",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "work" => Array
        (
            "0" => Array
                (
                    "employer" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "348468651959125",
                            "name" => "Karachi university"
                        ),

                    "location" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "110713778953693",
                            "name" => "Karachi, Pakistan"
                        ),

                    "position" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "1556082398000870",
                            "name" => "Lecturer"
                        ),

                    "start_date" => "2008-04-25"
                ),

             "1" => Array
                 (
                    "description" => "i am teaching......",
                    "end_date" => "2011-06-20",
                    "employer" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "486743441453589",
                            "name" => "Happy Palace Grammar School NORTH 3 - J2"
                        ),

                    "location" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "110713778953693",
                            "name" => "Karachi, Pakistan"
                        ),

                    "position" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "1556082398000870",
                            "name" => "Lecturer"
                        ),

                    "start_date" => "2005-06-17"
                )

        ),
    "education" => Array
        (
            "0" => Array
                (
                    "school" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "193563427344550",
                            "name" => "Mehran Model Sec School"
                        ),

                    "type" => "High School"
                ),

            "1" => Array
                (
                    "concentration" => Array
                        (
                            "0" => Array
                                (
                                    "id" => "104076956295773",
                                    "name" => "Computer Science"
                                )

                        ),

                    "school" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "113340788773685",
                            "name" => "Sir Adamjee Institute"
                        ),

                    "type" => "College",
                    "year" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "118118634930920",
                            "name" => "2012"
                        )

                ),

            "2" => Array
                (
                    "concentration" => Array
                        (
                            "0" => Array
                                (
                                    "id" => "104076956295773",
                                    "name" => "Computer Science"
                                )

                        ),

                    "degree" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "519451718218292",
                            "name" => "Bachelor of science in Computer Science in Computer Science"
                        ),

                    "school" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "107345492681211",
                            "name" => "SZABIST"
                        ),

                    "type" => "Graduate School",
                    "year" => Array
                        (
                            "id" => "127342053975510",
                            "name" => "2016"
                        )

                )

        ),

    "id" => "145864899647476"
);
```

and this is my code:

```
$keys = array_keys($profile);
print_r($keys);
echo count($profile);
echo "<br>";

for ($i=4; $i <count($profile)-1 ; $i++) { 
    # code...
    /*[4] => work [5] => education*/
    echo $keys[$i]."<br>";
    foreach ($profile[$keys[$i]] as $k => $v) {
        # code...
        echo "<br>$k<br>";
        $keeys=array_keys($v);
        print_r($keeys);
    }
}
```

Comment: so...what is your question?

Comment: you need to access the array for the 2 pieces of information you need?

Comment: yes i need the values of position=>name from work array and school=>name and type from education array.